# Decimal places deleted in R

Tags: r, dataframe, decimal

I have a data frame with a column full of 13-digit numbers. But there is a mistake there, there had to be a decimal point before the last 3 digits (e.g., the number `1582305791901` should have been `1582305791.901`).

So I thought I could easily solve this problem by simply dividing the entire column by 1000. But this does not preserve the decimal points, instead I get `1582305791`. How can I solve this? (P.S. The column is of type "numeric", not "integer".)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try running this option first

```
options(digits = 15)
```

Answer (score 0):

check if your number is stored as integer with `typeof` and `class`, then as.numeric(x)/1000